# Translation incluye nombres de Event aunque en el wiki dice que no lo hace

Tags: genexus

En https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6330,Application+Localization dice :

The automatic translation process translates every string constant that appears in your GeneXus code. Exceptions are:
String that follows the commands Do, Sub, Event (*) (i.e. Subroutines and Events names)

Pero me está poniendo todos los Event a traducir.

Saludos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Buenas, con que version de genexus estas trabajando? gracias